# Is Craft Magic Arms and Armor mandatory to add special abilities to an Amulet of Mighty Fists?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

The Amulet of Mighty Fists's requirements are as follows:

> Craft Wondrous Item, greater magic fang, creator’s caster level must
>   be at least three times the amulet's bonus, **plus any requirements of
>   the melee weapon special abilities**

I take the last line there to mean that the requirements of any of the weapon abilities you opt to add are essentially added to the list of requirements for the amulet (feel free to correct me if I'm wrong). If so, suppose I add the Frost property to the amulet. Frosts requirements are :

> Craft Magic Arms and Armor, chill metal or ice storm

This is where I get a little confused. In Pathfinder you can ignore requirements for making non-spell trigger/completion magic items by jacking up your spellcraft DC, with one exception:

> The DC to create a magic item increases by 5 for each prerequisite the
>   caster does not meet. The only exception to this is **the requisite item
>   creation feat**, which is mandatory.

My question is, can I ignore Craft Magic Arms and Armor, the "requisite" feat for Frost, because I'm just making an amulet (which already has its own corresponding requisite feat)? Or are these considered separate, with both requiring a mandatory feat?

Comment: One of the most common houserules or setting-items I see is a "fistwrap" that can be enchanted as a weapon.  Allowing them (and just treating them as weapons that do the character's unarmed strike damage) removes 95% of the desire to make the Amulet.  The other 5% want the amulet to boost their "monk-cheese-can-make-unarmed-attacks-with-my-hands-full" builds that grind out 12+ attacks per turn, and I have no problem requiring them to have every feat and spell under the sun :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the property’s requirements include the feat requirement, which is included in the statement that you need “any requirements” that the Special Property has.

Doesn’t seem appropriate to me, but that is what it says.

Comment: Seems appropriate to me. The feat mechanically reflects your knowledge of weapon properties and abilities, which is what you want to apply to the amulet.

Comment: What makes the Craft Magic Arms and Armour feat requirement different to all of the other requirements? Why can't that requirement be ignored with an increase to the Spellcraft DC?

Comment: @Jason_c_o It’s inappropriate because the item doesn’t deserve to be so much more difficult and costly than other items to craft. I wouldn’t care if the amulet required Craft Magic Arms & Armor *instead of* Craft Wondrous Item, but requiring both for that item is inappropriate.

Comment: @YogoZuno It’s different cuz *it is a feat requirement*, ya know, the one thing explicitly called out as an exception?

Comment: @KRyan A feat requirement, not THE feat requirement...

Comment: @YogoZuno And you find me a citation defining what *the* feat requirement would be, and you have a point. Until that time, however, your decision that it is Craft Wondrous Item and not Craft Magic Arms & Armor is pure houserule without any backing in the rules.

Comment: Well, the same could easily be said about your answer. Given the ambiguous nature of the situation, there is no clearcut answer.

Comment: Actually, coming back and re-reading, I'd have to cede that "the" implies the feat to craft the amulet itself which would be Craft Wondrous Items. I no longer think Arms and Armour is required; When reading the rules for Frost it is of course normally referring to Arms and Armour because it is normally a weapon property. BUT, I now believe, this should be interpreted in the context of the item you are creating (the amulet) and nothing else.

Comment: @Jason_c_o There’s absolutely no rules-basis for designating one feat *the* feat and the other not. Both are required feats.

Comment: One is required by the amulet, and one is required by the Frost enchant. Since the PC is altering an amulet, it falls under Wondrous Item. The requirements then, fall under a hierarchy by order of requirement: Craft Wondrous Item > Caster Level > Greater Magic Fang > Craft Arms and Armour > Chill Metal + Ice Storm. Seems pretty clear to me what "the" feat should be. So I'd rule that in lacking Arms and Armour, they can still craft but face the relevant negatives to the check.

Comment: @Jason_c_o “Pretty clear” if you follow a hierarchy found nowhere in the rules and that you just made up? Sure.

Comment: @KRyan Its not a rule I can cite, but when crafting the amulet and reading the rules you encounter the requirements for the amulet first and for frost later. Crafting amulets is governed by Wondrous Items, that *is* something citable. Show me a citation that shows you should consider Arms and Armour "the" feat and I'll gladly cede. Until then I'll have to go with what I believe are the RAI.

Comment: @Jason_c_o A. it says *the* feat not the *first* feat. Being first doesn’t mean anything because the rules don’t say it means anything. B. amulets are *usually* crafted using Craft Wondrous Item, but I’ll be surprised if you can cite anything saying they are *always* crafted *only* with Craft Wondrous Item. And my point isn’t that Craft Magic Arms & Armor is *the* feat, my point is that they are both, together, equally “the” feat and that “the” feat isn’t actually a thing of significance, merely sloppy editing that neglected to say “the feat *or feats*.”

Comment: @KRyan Show me one example of an amulet that is crafted with only Arms and Armour. Anyway, to me this seems a case of rule-lawyering and is therefore table-dependant. A GM could decide if either feat is necessary, as long as they keep one (RAW). Which one they choose is up to them and between them and their player.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13366/discussion-between-kryan-and-jason-c-o)

Answer (score 3):

You have quoted the relevant parts of the rules yourself - the text for ignoring prerequisites says 'the only exception to this is THE requisite item creation feat'. In other words, the only prerequisite you can't do without is the first Item Creation feat required for an enchanted item.

In almost all cases, only a single Item Creation feat is required. This is likely about the only case that needs two. I would rules that in this case, you can overcome no Craft Magic Arms and Armour by increasing the DC.

Comment: I actually think the feat should remain mandatory. Frost is a magic weapon special ability, and the feat mechanically reflects the characters knowledge about such properties.

Comment: An *amulet of mighty fists, frost* requires two feats, in contradiction of the quoted line that implies that there is only one. If you want to read that line as absolute, then this case *breaks the rule* because it is not addressed. The rule definitely does not say “with the exception of *one* requisite item creation feat,” nor does any rule suggest that Craft Wondrous Item is *the* feat as opposed to Craft Magic Arms and Armor which is... not *the* feat? This ruling is explicitly unsupported by the rules, and reads **way** too much into a lack of “or feats” in that sentence.

Comment: Actually coming back and re-reading this question.. I have to cede that "the" would simply mean the Craft Wondrous Items feat, and Arms and Armour would not be required.